# Find a DOM Element using an attribute-value which is acquired dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

There is already question about getting a dom element by using an attribute value. But mine is different because my attribute value is not known beforehand.

```
<div class='gameBoard'>
   <div class="grid" index='0'></div>
   <div class="grid" index='1'></div>
   <div class="grid" index='2'></div>
   <div class="grid" index='3'></div>
   <!-- Goes up to 100 div / 99 index values -->
</div>
```

I have a div gameboard representing a dom element which contains 100 div, each with the index values from 0 to 99. Below im looping through all the divs and when the mouse hovers over a div, than I gets its index ( data-attribute ). ( if the direction is on the x-axis, then I do this )

```
            const one = el;
            const onei = el.getAttribute('index');
            const two = el.nextElementSibling;
            const twoi = two.getAttribute('index');
```

But when the direction is on the y-axis, I don't need the next div element but the one below. For ex: if index is 0, I need 0 + 10 = 10, so i need the div with index 10. I tried the code below but it is not working cuz the value is retrieved dynamically, I tried using string interpolation and it doesn't work. So please help !!!

```
    const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');

    el.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    if (foo === 'destroyer' || foo === 'submarine') {
       if (currentDirection === 'Y') {
            const one = el;
            const onei = Number(el.getAttribute('index'));
            const twoi = onei + 10;
            const two = document.querySelector("[index='twoi']");
            console.log(two, twoi);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ```const two = document.querySelector(`[index='${twoi}']`);``` - Notice the backticks.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can you please put your comment as an answer. It worked  Thank you.

Comment: Take Suman's answer, which is correct. ;)

Comment: There is 3 set of *quote* in JS, single, double and backtick. Their positionning is important. Missing mispositionning or not escaping them is a common problem.

Comment: Thank you, ill look into that; I have been using them interchangeably.

Comment: Single and double are quite interchangeable in JS while there is common practices (read opiniated or code writing style preference) about which to use depending on the case... Backticks are [templating litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which is way more powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string **concatenation** inside querySelector is wrong

It should be working with this below code for that line

```
const two = document.querySelector(`[index="${twoi}"]`);
```

Comment: Im getting this error. main.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[index=10]' is not a valid selector.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/main.js:1:19681)

Comment: Changed the code a little bit in the ans
try this one 

`const two = document.querySelector(\`[index="${twoi}"]\`);`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that of string interpolation. You're literally looking for an element that has the index `twoi`. Insteady, try interpolating the string with back ticks, e.g.

```
const two = document.querySelector(`[index='${twoi}]'`);
```

or just adding the twoi string to it:

```
const two = document.querySelector("[index=" + twoi + "]");
```

Comment: Misplaced backtick and missing quote (for the first code suggestion).

Comment: I tried that,  im getting this error. main.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[index=10]' is not a valid selector.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/main.js:1:19669)

Comment: That's my bad. You need to wrap it in single quotes.

Comment: Misplaced single quote... lol!

Comment: it worked, thank you both for your time. 